# Recommendations for creating an iOS app which fetches JSON response and stores data in Core Data (for offline use)

Tags: ios, json, core-data, model, offline-caching

What would be the recommended procedure (such as pods or libraries) if I wanted to request JSON and then store the data in a Core Data model for both online and offline use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit), it is being actively developed.

From the GitHub repo:
It provides a powerful object mapping engine that seamlessly integrates with Core Data and a simple set of networking primitives for mapping HTTP requests and responses built on top of AFNetworking.